# why there are 2 php directories in C:\ and C:\xampp

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I have 2 **php** directories. One in **C:/** and the other in **C:/xampp** .
Have I installed php twice or is this normal.

I'am also getting a warning message when I try any php command
`php -version`

```sh
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2020 17:29:46) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Now if I want to edit the **php.ini** I can't decide which file to edit because in both `extension=fileinfo` is uncommented

Comment: Running a php file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` as content via your webserver will tell you which `php.ini` file is in use

Comment: " Have I installed php twice or is this normal." - most probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open php.ini from below:

[image]

Comment: will this open the ini file that is in the xampp/php

Comment: Yes it will open config as per your current server